# Can't view crashes in Xcode Organizer

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

In iTunes Analytics I can see that I am getting 8 crashes in my new iOS app.

[image: screenshot 1]

Sadly there is absolutely no way to actually view the crashes in that web UI, so I went to Xcode's Organizer and went to the Crashes tab for my app. It's empty. Other teammates have the same problem.

[image: screenshot 2]

What's going on, why are they not shown, and how do I get them to show up?

Some extra information: I am using Bitcode at the moment, `Debug Information Format` is set to `DWARF with dSYM file`, and I am using Bitrise as my CI tool, which builds the app and uploads the archive to Appstore Connect.

Comment: Have you clicked on the version number? It will bring up a list of all App Store versions. Maybe an older version is where the crashes are.

Comment: This is the correct version, but yes, I tried them all. None show crashes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds stupid but it worked for me once.

1. Remove your team within Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts.
2. Restart xCode. (perhaps even your Macbook)
3. Add your team again.
4. Check Organizer again.

If it still doesn't work (which I also had sometimes) I'd advise you to use something else. I know it's annoying but xCode's crash reports were simply never reliable enough for me (and the rest of the world I believe). So I'd go for Crashlytics (which for me works 100% reliably) or some other tool.

Comment: Sadly that didn't help :(

Comment: Ah too bad.. Hmm, I guess there's nothing left then to follow my last advice maybe. Sorry to hear it. Good luck!